# Ionic 2 Angular 2 JSON - Cannot read property 'x' of undefined, but x.field works

Tags: json, angular

in a Ionic2 project i have a page 'A' that call a service that provide the result of a JSON file. In 'A' page i'm able to read all the fields of every JSON element, and show them in the HTML. Than, I need to show some of this fields in another page 'B', so a push this page with one of this element (parameter).
In the page 'B', i can't read the fields of the element direclty from the HTML. The only way that works is to read every field separately.
I'll give you an example:

test.json:

```
{
"elements" : [
    {   "name":"Max",
        "age":"23"},
    {   "name":"John",
        "age":"31"}
]}
```

The provider GET call:

```
getElements(){
      return this.http.get('test.json').map(res => res.json());
}
```

page A getjson:

```
public myelements: any;
loadElements(){
      this.getjson.getElements().subscribe(
          result => {
              this.myelements=result.elements; 
          }
      );
  }
```

in the page A this works properly:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let ele of myelements" (click)="goToPageB(ele)">
{{ele.name}} and {{ele.age}}</div>
```

this (click) function is:

```
goToPageB(ele) {
      this.navCtrl.push(PageB, 
                        {ele: ele}
      )
  }
```

in the Page B, one way doesn't work, the other works. I don't understand why:

```
public myele: any; // the best way, not work
public myname: any; // the other way, works

ionViewDidLoad() { 
    this.myele = this.navParams.get('ele'); // the best way, but error
    //this.myname = this. navParams.get('ele').name; // this worse way works
```

finally, in the html of page B, if I use the best way:

```
<div>{{myele.name}} </div> 
<!-- error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined -->
```

if I use the other way, it works:

```
<div> {{myname}}</div>
```

I really don't understand why i'm not able to use directly the element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try to change it to:

```
<div>{{myele?.name}} </div>
```

Comment: when you were asking for the `name` of `myele`, actually for asynchronous behavior of Javascript calls the `myele` is not present .. so you add that `?` of Typescript you're actually saying `if it is present`.. Could you check or upvote Please ? ^^

Answer (score 1):

May be some one else finds it useful. Even though answer is **accepted**.
Try something like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-b',
      templateUrl: 'bPage.html'
    })
    export class BPage{
    public myele:any;
      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams:NavParams) {
           this.myele= navParams.get("ele");
      }

      ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('Hello page B');
      }

    }
```

**In View do something like this:**

```
<div>{{myele.name}}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it works. So the only difference is the 'get' into constructor instead of into ionViewDidLoad. Right?

Comment: Ok, now I'm a little confused. I'm going to search more information about ionViewDidLoad. Anyway, i can't upvote you because I do not have enough reputation

Comment: You should.  as long as it helps you to understand and makes you learn more that matters more than reputation or reputation score.